# Javascript - get n'th largest value for a particular key's values in array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

First, here's a quick snippet of the data I'm working with:

```
var myData = [
    {player: "Joe", team: "team1", stat: 15},
    {player: "Tom", team: "team3", stat: 23},
    {player: "Red", team: "team2", stat: 8},
    {player: "Smi", team: "team5", stat: 0},
    {player: "Bib", team: "team6", stat: 24},
    {player: "Cat", team: "team2", stat: 6},
    {player: "Dan", team: "team3", stat: 50},
    {player: "Jim", team: "team1", stat: 17}
]
```

Simple enough, I am trying to grab the n'th largest value from the *stat* key's values in *myData*, and then filter myData to include only the n objects where the *stat* key's value is greater than or equal to the n'th largest value. I am not too worried about how ties are handled (ie. if there is more than one value tied for n'th largest...

Still getting my feet wet with javascript, so any help with these data manip tasks are greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `sort()` them with a custom comparator and then dereference the `n`th item.  Please add an attempt.

Comment: So, if there are 5 n'th larger values, you want n + 4 elements, or just n?

Comment: ultimately i want n objects in the array

Comment: I am currently giving it an attempt

Comment: Did you check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

`ReturnHigherFrom(2) //Returns 2 with most higher stats`

```js
var myData = [
    {player: "Joe", team: "team1", stat: 15},
    {player: "Tom", team: "team3", stat: 23},
    {player: "Red", team: "team2", stat: 8},
    {player: "Smi", team: "team5", stat: 0},
    {player: "Bib", team: "team6", stat: 24},
    {player: "Cat", team: "team2", stat: 6},
    {player: "Dan", team: "team3", stat: 50},
    {player: "Jim", team: "team1", stat: 17}
];

console.log(ReturnHigherFrom(3));

function ReturnHigherFrom(nth){
    return myData.sort((a, b) => b.stat - a.stat).slice(0, nth);
}
```

*Edited to make shorter thanks to @ibrahimmahrir*

Comment: wasn't me, checking through the suggestions now

Comment: @MatheusCuba You can make the sort even shorter: `myData.sort((a, b) => b.stat - a.stat)`. I've deleted my answer after the unjustified downvote so feel free to use that.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I was downvoted too, I saw your anwser (didn't edit mine then to don't copy you), but thanks!

Comment: Yeah I've noticed. These abusive downvoters really get under my skin. If you don't like the question downvote the question. The question is clearly not a duplicate, so the downvotes you and I got aren't fair.